# Can i use Open DNS as well as my ISP's DNS in my Win 2008 DNS server forwarders?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I'm just wondering if it's bad to put in Open DNS ips in my win 2008 dns server's forwarders as well as the DNS ips from my ISP? Is it bad to have lots of DNS  forwarders?

Should i just use one set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bad idea I guess but consider this. If you are using OpenDNS to filter content what will happen when a request for objectionable content is forwarded to non-OpenDNS servers?? The request will succeed.

I think OpenDNS is a flexible and robust DNS solution and you should feel confident enough to use OpenDNS as your only forwarder.

You should have at least two dns servers in your forwarder list though, to ensure you still get DNS resolution if there is a problem with one of the servers.

Comment: As well as the blocking thing not working properly if you mix openDNS and non-openDNS servers, you also loose out on the security of OpenDNS. One of the best reason to use them is that they are secure, and hence should protect you from DNS spoofing, if you use a non-OpenDNS server as well then half your users will loose out on the security offered by OpenDNS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so, and there's nothing wrong with it.